# Errno 13 Permission denied: '/var/lib/apt/lists/

Tags: 16.04

Every time I try to delete files in BleachBit, this error appears:

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/lib/apt/lists/uy.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-backports_main_i18n_Translation-en': Command to delete /var/lib/apt/lists/uy.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-backports_main_i18n_Translation-en
```

Does anybody know what I need to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you run BleachBit as user you don't have write access to the apt archives then you cannot execute that kind of cleaning. Then you have two options:

1. or you disable the apt cleaning
2. or you run BleachBit as root (in the menu there should present that options ---> BleachBit (as root)

I suggest you the first option because you don't need to clean the apt archive and also it's a bad idea run BleachBit as root.